# How do you decode query strings containing arrays in Go?

Tags: go

How do you use Go to decode a query string structured like this?

`/comments?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3`

Right now this code:

```
query := r.URL.Query()
for k, _ := range query { fmt.Printf("%s\n", k) }
ids := query.Get("ids[]")
if (ids != "") {
    fmt.Printf("Ids: %s\n", ids)
}
```

results in:

```
ids[]
Ids: 1
```

Is there a built-in way to support this or am I going to have to parse this out by hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can do this by calling

```
r.ParseForm()
fmt.Printf("Ids from form: %s\n", r.Form["ids[]"])
```

which yields the following results:

```
Ids from form: [1 2 3]
```